# Problems with PPTP VPN on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, pptp

I have a PPTP VPN server set up on Ubuntu VPS and it works OK on my Mac, but when I connect to it on my Windows 7 machine, most sites work, but for some reason some others do not work – browser just can't reach them (they do work on Mac however). I can ping these sites. I have tried different browsers, got same result. One example of a site that doesn't work on Windows through VPN is http://qbank.ru

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, any ideas?

Comment: How did you set this VPN on Ubuntu ? Have you tried to set up a VPN in Windows with the built-in VPN and try if it works fine ?

Comment: I don't think it's a server issue, because everything works fine on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if you don't disable the Gateway option. Basically you will use the internet connection on the other side to browse the internet, causing all kinds of weird problems.

To change this, do the following:

```
 1. Open your network settings (control panel)
 2. Go to Change network settings
 3. Right Click your VPN connection and select properties
 4. Go to the tab Networking
 5. Doubleclick the TCP/IP v4 protocol
 6. Click Advanced
 7. Uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network
 8. Press OK 3 times. (3 dialogs)
 9. Disconnect and reconnect VPN
10. test again.
```

Comment: With this setting my VPN connection does not actually do anything – my public ip remains the same as it was without VPN.

Comment: What this setting does, is allows your client to access resources in the network without using up their internet. This way, all internet access (such as external sites) will be using your own internet conenction, which is much faster and isn't prone to all kinds of problems. If you really are looking for a way to tunnel your internet through your vpn, then you have to start looking at the server side. Can you still access those webpages if you open a webbrowser directly from the server? Your mac will also do what I suggested above, so thats not a good test.

Comment: Mac doesn't do that, all my traffic goes through VPN – that's what I want. All sites see my VPN ip.

Comment: I see. Okay. What I'd do then is go to the setting as discribed above, and manually enter the ip adress of the VPN server as gateway adress, so the DNS will look up through that.

Comment: Where is the gateway address setting? I can't find it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I ment DNS server.

Comment: With "Use default gateway on remote network" options turned on, all sites stop working - can't connect. Without that option sites work, but they still see my ISP ip, not the VPN one.